# Is it good practice to use Docker in a Cloud Function?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am using a Cloud function that is triggered by a bucket to process that file and save the result in another bucket. (more specfically using Pyinstaller to compile python files into executable). However it is cumbersome to operate with a read-only filesystem where I can only use the /tmp folder also with an underlying operating system that lacks some system packages I need.
Using docker could solve my problem but not sure whether I should use in a cloud function or in another way.

Comment: Doug's answer is the best so far, but more information is required to answer your question. Your use case appears to not be a good candidate for Cloud Functions or Cloud Run. Look at App Engine Standard, App Engine Flexible or Compute Engine optionally running Container OS. Compute Engine F1 instances are cheap (about $6.00 per month).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cloud Functions already uses a containerized environment.  Trying to add another layer of container to that won't really help anything, and probably make things worse (if you can even get it to work, which I highly doubt).  You'll still have the same underlying resources available, which does not involve any local disk space, and the same amount of memory for reading and writing files in a tmp-based filesystem.

Cloud Run allows you to deploy a container, but that still [doesn't involve local disk space](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tips#deleting_temporary_files).

If you really need local disk space that exceeds the /tmp provided by the class of machine you've chosen to do your work, Cloud Functions isn't the best place to do that work.  Consider instead using [Compute Engine, which provides local storage options](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/). You can still use Cloud Functions for product triggers, but you will have to delegate the work to Compute Engine.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Run is best option if you want to use containerised application.